# How to fill listbox from a List without any loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one Listbox and a List of data

I want to bind the list to listbox.

So any Idea any example please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you Can bind your data to the listbox.

as bellow

```
ListBox1.DataSource = listSource;
ListBox1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 3):

lstbx.DataSource = list;

lstbx.DisplayMember = "FirstName";

http://sharpertutorials.com/list-box-data-binding/